# Video (but not audio) lags

Tags: 12.04

I recently updated Ubuntu from 10.04 to 12.04, and the video playback on sites such as VEVO and other flash-style sites utilizing video seem to lag considerably, sometimes even completely unwatchable.

How do I fix that?

Comment: PC/laptop brand?

What sound card you have? Video card?

Comment: This may also be a flash problem, since you said it happens because of Flash. Have you tried to watch videos from non-Flash websites such as [YouTube](http://youtube.com)? It uses HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated everything using update manager? Also try this [eHow article](http://www.ehow.com/how_8373440_update-flash-player-ubuntu-terminal.html), also.

Comment: You should consider putting short answers like these into the comments section. Otherwise, you should use the information you learned from that website and recreate it while in Ubuntu if you can, giving useful step-by-step instructions - making it a ***helpful and informative*** answer. You could also use the link as a **source**. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, don't forget to read the [FAQs](http://askubuntu.com/faq) and have a nice day :)